# Move Microsoft Edge User Data to new computer

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge

My problem is that when I copy the Appdata/Local/Microsoft/Edge/User Data/Default folder to a new PC, only part of it is taken over. The home page, the default search engine and the search engine used in the address bar are not adopted.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: For most of us, I reckon, moving our favorites is the key thing.  New home page is really easy, as is default search engine.

Comment: I have transferred Edge user profiles, in my experience, all that’s required is copy the profile directory. In your case what isn’t being transferred?

Comment: @John Unfortunately, it has to be possible to take over everything, as this should be done automatically via PowerShell later.

Comment: @Ramhound the home page, the default search engine and the search engine used in the address bar are not being transfered.

Comment: All of those settings should be synchronized. Must have missed read your sentence, only reason I asked.

Comment: "the default search engine and the search engine used in the address bar are not being transfered." I would be surprised if this is not on purpose. Edge and Bing are made by the same org (WebXT), they are meant to boost each other in user adoption

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73579772/where-are-edge-browser-other-search-engines-settings-stored

Comment: @Layman - It’s not. The default search can be changed. All Chromium browsers can change the default search engine.

Comment: @Layman but I want to set the settings with powershell or copy the default profile. But not all settings like the default search engine and the search engine used in the address bar could be transferred to new computer. But why? 

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?